# What plant crops can grow using only 75% light intensity?

Tags: biology, environment, agriculture, farming

Are there any plant crops that can grow reliably well at only 75% light illumination?

Comment: For the context of...? What exactly are you referring to by percentage of light intensity ? Where are said crops growing?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "75% light illumination".  Canada gets less than 75% of the sunlight (per m^2) than at the equator, yet a considerable number of plants grow there.  Plants also grow quite well in places where solar intensity is considerably reduced by cloud cover, or being in the understory of forests.

Answer (score 0):

Mushrooms.

They can be grown in caves.

Comment: Can you really consider mushrooms a "crop"?

Comment: @DonThousand Why woudn't you? They can be, and are, farmed.

Comment: Mushrooms are fungi, not plants.  Fungi are actually more closely related to animals.